# QGIS - auto fill values in one column which share the same value in a different column

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, conditional, column

There are three columns in the attribute table.

- `part`, `forest` with both unique IDs and `factor` with three possible values (yes, no, check).
- One `forest` contains many different `part`.

If the `factor` is changed to "yes" for one `part` of a `forest`, the column `factor` should be automatically updated to "yes" for all "parts" which are in the same "forest" and therefore share the same `forest` ID.

Of course there are ways to do this manually but an automatic solution would be great as the database is huge. So basically I am looking for an automatic fill for one column, but only for the lines which share the same value in a different column.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. While to processing necessary to do such update is pretty basic, the definition of "automatic" is a problem here.  If the data were in a SQL database, a TRIGGER could be created, and "automaticness" would be a SQL statement.  If the data source doesn't support events, then an explicit script would need to be written, following the manual procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, part makes no difference, only forest?

Create a function in the python editor and call it with `autofill()` when you have set some row to yes:

```py
def autofill():
    lyr = iface.activeLayer() #Make sure to click the layer name in table of contents
    yeses = {f['forest'] for f in lyr.getFeatures() if f['factor']=='yes'} #Find all forests with a yes in factor field
    factor_field_index = lyr.fields().indexFromName('factor') #Find field index of the factor field
    am = {} #A dictionary to hold the values to update
    if yeses: #If there are any forests in yeses set
        for f in lyr.getFeatures(): #For each feature in the table
            if f['forest'] in yeses: #Check if the features forest is in yeses set
                am[f.id()] = {factor_field_index:'yes'} #If it is, add it to the dictionary
        lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(am) #And update it
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :), it worked!